# What is exact definition of pure Linux?

Tags: linux

I have abstractly thought of `Pure Linux` as a just Linux which has only basic functions.

What is the exact definition of Pure `Linux`?

How far is it different from Ubuntu or something ?

How can I download the Pure Linux image?(I want to install it on virtual machine)

Comment: You can download the Linux kernel here: https://www.kernel.org/

Answer (score 2):

### Literal Answer

Linux in its pure form is a monolithic kernel made by Linus Torvalds. It is the hypothalamus of any GNU/Linux distribution- allocating resources to processes. (the stuff you see with ps -x) Linux distros are useless without a Linux kernel and Linux kernel is useless without a userland, mostly provided by GNU. And then there's distros...

---

### In Common Parlance

You'll probably here that some distros are closer to "pure linux". Linux is a Unix-like Operating System, emphasis on "like". UNIX is a brand of sorts- a club of systems meeting certain specifications based on a computer from the 70s. There is nothing inherently better about UNIX. (The *NIX family on the other hand is objectively better.) Sure Solaris is delightful for its old-school charm alone, but so is DOS. (Think IBM and early Microsoft) Indeed the most popular UNIX operating system does not represent the noble values of GNU / Linux. That would be... Mac OSX! (cue booing) BSD is awesome though. Anyway, Linux belongs to a related but less exclusive club of **POSIX compliant** Operating Systems. That's a way Linux can be pure- adherence to the POSIX standard. The majority of distros are indeed POSIX compliant. Another way "pure" is used is "light-weight". Less bloat. A distro with a smaller userland is closer to pure linux kernel, is it not? Another way pure is used is "doing things in a super antiquated way for nostalgia value". In a word, Slackware, the UNIXiest of them all. Its package manager can't resolve dependencies, like in the good old days.  Begone, haters!